# Create notifications in yammer

Tags: yammer

Hi I Have a MVC application and I want to notifiy selected people/Group in yammer about certain actions happening in my MVC application. My preference of notifying is as follows

1. Notifications
2. Messages

I dont want to use Open graph because from my understandign it will post the notiifcation on News Feed. I want it to appear under notification icon ( bell sign on top ). Is it possible ? If not, can I create messages for certain people/groups in thier inbox for it ?

What will be challanges/issues? if anyone can summarize that will be great help.

another thing is I want to see complete list of Rest-APIs available in yammer. Can someone help me out on it also ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Here's the link to the REST api docs on the developer site. http://developer.yammer.com/restapi/

Comment: Hi Macro..thanks for link..I saw the API documentation but I didn't found any API for posting notification..there is API to fetch notifications...I know I can post message but I want to know if Notification can be posted or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not allow you to create notifications directly.

You can instead post a message to Yammer in two ways:
- As a PM to a user
- As a post in a group, with a set of users CC'ed

In both cases, users will get the message in their inbox and the inbox unread counter will increment.

I imagine you would want to send these messages from a bot account.